# Function is changing array from numeric to associative

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is supposed to take any rows where `ing_name` is duplicated, combine the `eff_name` fields and delete the duplicate but it also has the side effect of changing the array from numeric to associative. My ajax is expecting numeric array.

```
for($i=count($recipe)-1; $i>0; $i--) {
    if($recipe[$i]['ing_name'] == $recipe[$i-1]['ing_name']) { //check for duplicate. **array must be sorted by ing_name**
        $recipe[$i-1]['eff_name'] .= ', '.$recipe[$i]['eff_name']; //Combine eff_name of duplicates
        $recipe[$i-1]['link'] = true;
        unset($recipe[$i]); //remove duplicate index
    }
}
```

examples: [NUM](http://tidehousedesign.com/alchemy/php/alchemy.php?json&eff=damage%20magicka), [ASSOC](http://tidehousedesign.com/alchemy/php/alchemy.php?json&eff=damage%20magicka,%20damage%20magicka%20regen)

[Source](https://github.com/Tidehouse/Alchemy)

EDIT: So i figured it must have something to do with unsetting the index so I did this and it seems to work ok:

```
$newRecipe = array();
foreach($recipe as $r) {
    $newRecipe[] = $r;
}
```

New question, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unset` works with named keys. You could use [`array_splice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) instead, or get a brand new array after the loop with [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) (but that would be ugly!).

Comment: Nevermind, array_splice led me to array_slice which I ended up using because I only need to remove one index at a time. Thanks!

Comment: Because you are creating a new array, after disfiguring the original one. If you use `array_splice` inside the loop instead of `unset`, you don't need to create a new array, as the original code intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

[array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) Will return a numerically indexed array